# Gradle sync error in android studio 3.0.1 with gradle build 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[image: Below is the screenshot of the error, Any help will really be appreciated.]

This error pops up every time I load a new project or either create a one,
Thi error is bugging me for 2 weeks any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: delete **cache** folder from **.gradle** folder and try again

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors which you can encounter on installing the AS 3.0.1. Most common of which are -

**Error 1** *Error: Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2 “install.build.tools” Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project.*

**Solution:** In *build.gradle* file update the configuration because right now it is looking for API 26. If you check in the SDK Manager, it shows that you actually have version 27. So, there is no need to install the SDK of API level 26, rather update the configuration in *build.gradle* file as follows":

**=>** Change the *compileSdkVersion* from 26 to 27 and change the *targetSdkVersion* from 26 to 27.

**Error 2** *Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2
"install.build.tools" Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project.*

**Solution:** In the same *(build.gradle)* file, add *buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"* just below *compileSdkVersion 27*. The code must somewhat appear like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.happybirthday"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

After these changes the studio should work fine and you'll be able to begin your development. One more way to verify the same is that you must now see an *'Android'* submenu under *'Tools'* in the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, go to "C:\Users{user_name}\", you will find folder **.gradle**. Delete it and go back to your Android Studio and click the menu **Build>Clean Project** or **Build>Rebuild Project**. Note, you must have Internet connection.

Comment: **Build > Rebuild Project** executes **Clean project** first, so you don't have to run those two tasks

Comment: @Variag I mean *OR*